# What are some synonyms for 'Benefactor'?

Tags: synonyms

Is there any synonyms for benefactor that also mean 'someone who makes others do good in the world'?

Comment: Once you know about a [**thesaurus**](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/benefactor) you can easily find a word such as [**philanthropist**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/philanthropist).

Comment: Someone who *makes others do good*? I assume the implication is that they make others do good by leadership or good example, rather than by force or compulsion. The appropriate term may be "moral leader" or "ethical leader". Religion tends to perform similar functions, and depending on exactly how the function is performed, official terms might include "preacher", "pastor", or similar. Also, the appropriate terms for the likes of Warren Buffet, Bill Gates, et al, may be the "penitent", since they are often relieving perceived problems that their own vast riches created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patron would be the best synonym. A philanthropist is a person who helps mankind in general, while a patron is somebody who gives a gift or support to a specific person of organisation. Hope that helps!

Comment: I meant to say patron. Thanks for spotting that.